# Cisco 2600 as DHCP server

Tags: networking, cisco, router

A very simple question that I seem unable to find a straight forward google answer for:

how do I setup a Cisco 2600 series router as a DHCP server for a network and also how do I set DHCP options (such as DNS server etc) ?

thanks

Comment: Which version IOS software?

Comment: IOS version is 12.0(5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much the same across all versions of the IOS you might be running on a 2600 router. I'm also assuming you are familiar with general Cisco router configuration (e.g. exec mode, privileged mode, configuration mode, etc.) I've included a few of the common DHCP option in this configuration example excerpt:

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.16.1.1 172.16.1.10
!
ip dhcp pool NAMEHERE
 network 172.16.0.0 /24
 domain-name cisco.com
 dns-server 172.16.1.5 172.16.1.6
 default-router 172.16.1.1
```

Note that each pool you create needs a unique, case-sensitive, name (NAMEHERE in this example). In the example the first 10 addressed of the subnet are reserved for static use (DHCP will start with 172.16.1.11) and the clients will receive a primary and secondary DNS server as well as a default gateway.

See the [Cisco documentation on DHCP pools from IOS 12.2](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfdhcp.html#wp1001302) for more information and options.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Ben. It's surprising how the simplest things in IOS are so hard to find out.

Comment: How does one display current DHCP server settings?

Comment: Just show the running config `show run`

Comment: sh run and show ip dhcp bind